# What is the difference between Selected Linked and Selected Linked All?

Tags: modeling, vertices, selection-tools, linked-data, select

In the Edit mode, I select one vertex, and then press <kbd>L</kbd>. As a result, `6091` out of `6096` vertices are selected. The Adjust Last Operation panel says "*Select Linked*".

[image]

In the Edit mode, I select one vertex, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. The result is the same: `6091` out of `6096` vertices are selected. But, the Adjust Last Operation panel says "*Select Linked All*".
[image]

So what is the difference between *Selected Linked* and *Selected Linked All* please? Thanks!

Comment: select is one thing and select all is bulk of selected items.

Comment: Thank you for the very concise answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer: *Select Linked* with <kbd>L</kbd> can select all connected vertices/edges/faces by just hovering your mouse over it and pressing the key, whereas *Select Linked All* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> needs a selection in one way or another first and then selects all connected vertices/edges/faces of this selection.

The longer answer, additionally to what I've said before: Since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> needs an initial selection first, to add to an existing selection you have to make a new selection while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> (if you don't want to lose the previous selection) and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> again. With the <kbd>L</kbd> key you just need to hover over a different new part to add it to the existing selection, the previous one will be kept.

The very important difference now is, since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> selects **all** connected vertices of an **existing selection**, it selects also those parts of a mesh which you may have left intentionally unselected.

Example: You have the following mesh as shown in the screenshot. On the sphere there is an already selected area. Now you also want to select the two separate parts on the right.

[image: select linked, premise]

If you would like to do that with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, you would have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select at least one vertex on each of those pieces. But now comes the problem: *Select Linked All* selects **all** vertices connected to the selected ones. The result would be the following:

[image: select linked all]

Let's say the mesh would be more complex and you had a hard time making the selection on the sphere and intended to keep the unselected areas, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is not the right tool because it selects every connected part.

If you instead move your mouse first over one piece on the right, press <kbd>L</kbd>, then the next and press <kbd>L</kbd> again, you get this:

[image: select linked]

Another thing is, maybe you accidentally hit <kbd>L</kbd> over the wrong piece - which can easily happen in a complex or confusing mesh without manually selecting a vertex beforehand - you can simply deselect it by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. This is not possible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, there you have to undo your action which might be very helpful if you realize it late that you have a wrong part selected.

The advantage of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on the other hand is, you can have very many single vertices selected through whatever option, tool etc. and with one step you can select everything connected which might take more steps with just using <kbd>L</kbd>. The best is working with both tools in combination, I guess.

Comment: As a Blender learner, I like how you explain the difference by providing a practical example to make me understand why Blender Foundation designed the selection tool in the current way - the reason to cause this difference. Thank you!

Comment: @BlenderLake You're welcome. I wanted to give a better overview since the difference between the tools is a little more complicated than selecting single things vs. all things or works with selection vs without selection. Especially the part that L keeps existing selections on unconnected meshes is very fundamental I think.

Answer (score 6):

With **Select Linked**, you don't need to select one vertex, you can just hover it with the mouse and press L.

With **Select Linked All**, you need to select at least one vertex.

Comment: What a great observation!

Comment: @BlenderLake I'm a bit late to the party, I tried to clarify the differences a bit more.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann   “A wizard is never late. Nor is he early. He arrives precisely when he means to.” From: Gandalf the Gray..... Your detailed solution surprised me! Because of this, I will mark the most helpful solution as the final answer tomorrow, instead of today now. Thank you!