# Select element like in 3DS Max?

Tags: modeling, faces

I know Blender has a very unique layout that it becomes so complex compared to Max.
I just need to know if I there's a way to select all of the faces that's part of a high detailed object by just clicking on one polygon. If I want to detach an object, I'd have to spend minutes and minutes selecting every little polygon one by one.

Comment: You mean select all faces that are contiguously linked ? Select > Select Linked > Linked or CTRL L

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. But I guess I'll have a hard time with the faces that are linked to other details of the object that I don't want selected.

Comment: It would be way easier if you just showed a little snippet or diagram of the thing you are trying to achieve, because as it stands apart from a rant about the features apparently not present in Blender compared to Max, your question is a little hard to decipher. :)

Comment: if you want to make some faces of the same mesh not selectable by Ctrl L you can create some seams, then when you select, make sure that the Delimit > Seam option is activated in the Operator box

Comment: To select all faces connected to a certain face, you do not have to select anything first, just hover your mouse over this certain face and press L. This selects all connected faces under the mouse. This might not seem to work if you are in _Vertex Select_ or _Edge Select_ mode instead of _Face Select_. In this case your mouse needs to be on or close to an edge or vertex. If you selected the wrong area, hover over it and press Shift+L. The good thing is, using L keeps existing selections without having to hold down shift to add selections.

Comment: A more in-depth overview how _Select Linked_ (L) and _Select Linked All_ (Ctrl+L) work and what are the main differences and advantages or disadvantages you will find in my answer here: [What is the difference between Selected Linked and Selected Linked All?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252752/what-is-the-difference-between-selected-linked-and-selected-linked-all/252783#252783)

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Ok so, now it brings me to my next question if I can ask. Would it be possible to select faces from editing UV's and then separate them?

Answer (score 0):

Try to select one face of your model and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: What does Ctrl + L do, could you elaborate? This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps or the final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).